# Unable to import classes in Typescript using amd

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript project in which I have a class Question defined in one file and a function that instantiates the Question class in another. I am not able to get this instantiation done, because Typescript throws an error on instantiation that says:

```
error TS 2095: Could not find symbol 'Question'
```

Here's the code:

```
//main.ts

import questionModule = require("./Question");
var Question = questionModule.Question;
function start() {
    var question1 = new Question();
}

//Question.ts

import mainModule = require("./Main");

export class Question{

...
}
```

How I can instantiate the Question object in main. It works fine when class Question is defined in the same file, but I need to separate them for modularization. This class does not have a constructor. And this is front end code compiled with amd.

--UPDATE

This code in the main file and in the Question file also throw errors:

```
//main.ts

class QuestionView{

    constructor(question:Question) {
       ...
    }
}

error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'Question'


//Question.ts

export class Question {

    start() {
        return{
            question: " ",
            yesOrNo: false,
            answers: new Answers([])
        }
    }

}

error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'Answers'.
```

The Answers definition is available in the main file which I have removed to avoid cyclic references. I have created typescript reference tags between both files.

========

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a *cyclic reference* importing `main.ts` in `question.ts`, don't see a reason for this:

```
import mainModule = require("./Main");
```

Also make sure your filenames match the import name (case sensitivity). As you can see it works fine:

[image]

**Update** Move `answers` into their own file `answers.ts` and import it into question as well as main.

Comment: I added the cyclical reference because there was a reference to another from the Question file to the main file. I've commented it out , but it still does not work. The reference made from the Question file throws an error: TS 2095: Could not find symbol

Comment: Try the code I've shown in the update above. It doesn't work. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @EternallyCurious move `answers` into their own file `answers.ts`